# Find Memory app is using in instrument?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, instruments

I'm debugging my App through instruments. To figure out the memory, my app,  is using through **Activity Monitor** **Instrument**.

Which one is the real memory my App is using?

-*All heap & Anonymous VM*

or

*All heap Allocations*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All heap allocations is a more accurate indicator of how much memory your app is using. Keep in mind the Allocations instrument does not measure texture memory so your real memory usage is all heap allocations plus texture memory.

Comment: how do i know the texture memory?

Comment: The Activity Monitor instrument should tell you the total memory being used, including the texture memory. The Allocations instrument doesn't tell you the texture memory being used, but it lets you find the areas of your code that are allocating memory.